Inequality regarding minimal perimeter sets
My professor was teaching out of Connor Mooney's notes on Minimal Surfaces and I missed a couple classes and am trying to catch up and I am having trouble understanding the proof of theorem 5.12 (uniform density estimates, pg. 20). At some point, they claim the inequality. Let $E$ be a minimizer to the perimeter problem in $B_1$ (ie. outside of $B_1$, $E=L$ for some measurable set $L$, and $E$ minimizes $P(E,B_1)$) and let $n$ be the dimension and let $0 \in \partial E$:

$$P(E \cap B_r, \mathbb R^n) \leq P(E,B_r) + |E \cap \partial B_r|_{\mathcal H^{n-1}} \leq C |E \cap \partial B_r|_{\mathcal H^{n-1}} $$

Here $\mathcal H^{n-1}$ is the $n-1$ dimensional Hausdorff measure and $C$ is some constant. They do not explicitly make a justification for the first inequality and I am having a hard time proving this to myself. I managed to come up with the following, fix $\epsilon>0$, choose $\psi \in C_c^1(\mathbb R^d,\mathbb R^d)$ such that $|\psi| \leq 1$ and:
$$P(E \cap B_r, \mathbb R^n) = \sup_{g \in C_c^1(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R^d), |g| \leq 1}\int_{E \cap B_r}|\nabla \cdot g| \leq \epsilon + \int_{E \cap B_r} |\nabla \cdot \psi|$$
Then let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(B_r)$ be radially symmetric and in between $[0,1]$:
\begin{align*}
P(E \cap B_r, \mathbb R^n) &  \leq \epsilon + \int_{E \cap B_r} |\nabla \cdot \psi|\\
& \leq \int_{E \cap B_r}|\nabla \cdot (\psi\varphi)|+\int_{E \cap B_r}|\nabla \cdot (\psi(1-\varphi))| + \epsilon\\
& \leq P(E,B_r)+\int_{E \cap B_r}|\nabla \cdot (\psi(1-\varphi))| +\epsilon\\
& \leq P(E,B_r)+\int_{E \cap B_r}|(\nabla \cdot \psi )(1-\varphi)| + \int_{E \cap B_r} |\nabla \varphi| +\epsilon\\
\end{align*}
Now as I take $\phi \to 1$ in $L^1$, the second term disappears. I think the third term becomes bounded by $|E \cap \partial B_r|_{\mathcal H^{n-1}}$ if I choose the right sequence, but I fail to see how this works. So if someone could please help me out here that would be great.
Additionally, for the second inequality, they provide the justification that since $E$ is a minimizer, we must have:
$$P(E,B_r) \leq |E \cap \partial B_r|_{\mathcal H^{n-1}}$$
Since $E$ subtracted $B_r$ would be a competitor (and so in fact the constant is $2$). But by this logic, wouldn't I technically get:
$$P(E,B_1) \leq P(E \backslash B_r, B_1)$$
And now to get the former from the latter, I feel like one would need to cite some very strong theorem like De Giorgi's theorem, but since we haven't covered essential boundaries in the class I'm taking I do not believe this is the right justification. So if someone could please help me out on this claim as well that would be great.
Thanks!
